# restkit google maps

Tags: ios, json, google-app-engine, restkit

I'm using RestKit v0.20.0-pre6 for iOS. My input is JSON from a service running on Google App Engine. This is what is being returned from the service:

```
  {
    action:"NOP",
    payload:null,
    timeStamp:new Date(1359427714679),
    type:null
  }
```

This is the error I'm getting displayed from RestKit in the output window:

```
  E restkit.network:RKResponseMapperOperation.m:240 
  Failed to parse response data: Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'application/json'
```

It is choking when NSJSONSerialization is called to parse the data. I'm sure it is the line that contains `new Date(1359427714679)`, but I am unsure on how to parse this line. The RestKit documentation mentions writing your own formatter, but I'm unclear on how to do this.

Any insight on how to solve this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of problems with your JSON here. Firstly, your keys need to be in inverted commas "". Secondly, your web service needs to provide the timestamp as a string.

Try ISO8601 format, e.g.

```
{
"action" :"NOP",
"payload" : null,
"timeStamp" : "1901-12-13T20:45:52+00:00",
"type": null
}
```

You can check that your JSON is valid by pasting it into an online validator such as http://www.jslint.com/.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, the JSON was incorrect. I was able to get the code changed on the server. -David